# Importing tables and Tablepress like plugin functionality

Tags: plugins, import, table

Is there a plugin or something equivalent to Tablepress (WordPress) for Craft?

I have some large Excel table containing product pricings amongst other things, that I would like to import into Craft and manage there.

Answer (score 4):

How do you plan to manage it in Craft?

If you want each row as a separate entry, create a section to hold the data, setup the fields you want to use to match each column, then use [Bob Olde Hampsink's import plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) to bring in the data. The plugin allows you to map the data to the fields in Craft.

Craft supports [tables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/table-fields) natively but you need a way to import them. You can use Bob's import plugin but you'll need to use the plugin's hooks to get the data where you want it. Tables in Craft are [stored as JSON](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/inserting-data-into-a-table-fieldtype-via-plugin) so you have to do some data wresting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying out Craft to see if I can migrate over to it from a current Wordpress system. And managing external tables of data is one of the last remaining issues. If you look at the [screenshots here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/screenshots/), ideally thats the way I would like to manage it. Each table is then accessed in the templates like an object, where all table data can easily be parsed in whatever way is needed. I will check out the resources you provided.

Answer (score 2):

How about [this one](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable)? It's a table field type.

Comment: I saw that one, thanks. But I don't see SuperTable supporting import of CSV files. I have 3-400 rows of data coming from Excel, that need to be uploaded in Craft admin in some way.